# Integration of $\int \frac{e^x}{e^{2x} + 1}dx$

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I came across this question and I was unable to solve it. I know a bit about integrating linear functions, but I don't know how to integrate when two functions are divided. Please explain. I'm new to calculus.

Question: $$\int \frac{e^x}{e^{2x} + 1}dx$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $u=e^x$. Integrate. You should  end up with $\arctan u+C$.  Note that there is no **general** procedure for finding the integral of \frac{f(x)}}{g(x)}$ even when we know everything about the integrals of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: When I try doing that, I end up with: (int)du/(u^2 + 1)

Comment: Yes, and $\int \frac{du}{1+u^2}=\arctan u+C$. Standard integral. If you do not recognize it, let $u=\tan t$.

Comment: Nice nickname! :-) Mathematicians are so mean. Euclid, the meanest of all, goes around stealing breakfasts and making people cry. :-)

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: See also [How to integrate $\int \frac{e^x dx}{1\,+\,e^{2x}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162238/how-to-integrate-int-fracex-dx1-e2x)

Answer (score 2):

You may write
$$
\int \frac{e^x}{e^{2x} + 1}dx=\int \frac{d(e^x)}{(e^{x})^2 + 1}=\arctan (e^x)+C
$$ since
$$
\int \frac{1}{u^2 + 1}du=\arctan u+C.
$$

Comment: I'm not able to understand how (int)1/(u^2 + 1)du = arctanu + C

Comment: @EuclidAteMyBreakfast, it's a rule you should probably know. $(arctan u)'=\frac{1}{1+u^2}$. As for proving that, use $\tan(\arctan(x))=x$. Thus by the chain rule $\arctan'(x)(tan^2(\arctan(x))+1)=1$, that is $\arctan'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot  :)